# Call get method of class in java

Tags: java

Can anyone please help me how to call the getId method of TestClass from the plain Object.
Can you please check the below sample.

```
package com;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Tes");
        Object d = new TestClass();
        System.out.println(d.getClass());// Trying to call the getId method of TestClass
    }
}
```

//TestClass

```
package com;

public class TestClass {
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Don't declare `d` as an `Object`, declare it as an instance of `TestClass`: `TestClass d = new TestClass();`. Then you can just call `d.getId()`.

Answer (score 4):

You first need to instantiate the class:

`TestClass c = new TestClass();`

Then you can access to its methods:

`int id = c.getId()`

Your problem is that you're putting the newly instantiated class into an `Object` (the highest level of inheritance) and thus you can only access to the methods declared there.